# Better ways to write this JQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page load/reload I want to keep the first button with a background-color, and when another button is clicked, that first button color disappear.

I have made this code for it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".target1").css("background-color", "red");
  $(".target1").css("color", "white");
  $(".target2").click(function(){
    $(".target1").css("background-color", "transparent");
    $(".target1").css("color", "black");
    $(".target2").css("background-color","red");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collapse3">
<ol>
<button class="target1" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/1.html')">F01-Fabrication-1</button><br>
                        
<button class="target2" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/2.html')">F01-Fabrication-2</button><br>
                        
<button class="target3" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/3.html')">F01-Fabrication-3</button><br>
                        
<a class="target4" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/4.html')">F01-Fbuttonbrication-4</button><br>
                        
<button class="target5" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/5.html')">F01-Fabrication-5</button><br>
 </ol>
</div>
```

I have lots of other buttons, so doing this kind of code in Jquery I think it isn't the best practice...I need help to explain to me a better way to do this? I will appreciate your teachings!

Thanks

Comment: [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `this` function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".target").css("color", "black").css("background-color", "white");
  $(".target1").css("background-color", "red");
  $(".target1").css("color", "white");
  $(".target").click(function() {
    $(".target1").css("background-color", "none");
    $(".target").css("color", "black").css("background-color", "white");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="target target1" type="button">
  Button 1
</button>
<button class="target target2" type="button">
  Button 2
</button>
<button class="target target3" type="button">
  Button 3
</button>
<button class="target target4" type="button">
  Button 4
</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/nje59zhz/2/)

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Moved to code snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can make it smaller like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collapse3">
  <ol>
    <button class="target1 btn" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/1.html')">F01-Fabrication-1</button>
    <br>

    <button class="target2 btn" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/2.html')">F01-Fabrication-2</button>
    <br>

    <button class="target3" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/3.html')">F01-Fabrication-3</button>
    <br>

    <a class="target4" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/4.html')">F01-Fbuttonbrication-4</button><br>
                        
<button class="target5" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/FAB/F01-Fabrication/5.html')">F01-Fabrication-5</button><br>
 </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting more then one property try:

```
$("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
```

pass an object in css() method.